# Cannot open bootstrap datetimepicker in iphone meteor app

Tags: jquery, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, bootstrap-datetimepicker

we have used bootstrap datetimepicker in our meteor app. Bootstrap datetimepicker works perfectly fine in android app and all desktop browser but in IOS app, it doesnt open, we have to touch the div/txbox for like 5 second or more in order to open it. Tried with click event and it opens on click event but then date cannot be changed at all. It always selects todays date no matter which date we select in dialog box

HTML Content

```js
<div id="datepicker" name="date">
 <input id="date1"  name="date" class="set-due-date datepicker staticBuyerPlaceHolder" type="text" placeholder="Date" style="width:100%;" readonly>         
</div>
```

Javascript

```js
this.$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    minDate: moment().add(-1, 'days'),
    date: oChild.value,
    sideBySide: true,
    stepping: 5, /* Increments for minutes*/
    //defaultDate : false,
    toolbarPlacement: 'top',
    /* keepOpen : true, *//*Will cause the date picker to stay open after selecting a 
                      date if no time components are being used.*/
    showClose : true, /* Shows close icon */
    ignoreReadonly: true
}); 

'dp.change #datepicker': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("change event " + event.date + " " + event.oldDate + " " + event.currentTarget.value);
},

'click #datepicker': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    template.$(".datepicker").data("DateTimePicker").show();
},
```

Comment: "all Desktop browser" so Safari web is also working when opening the same page from web via iPhone?

Comment: Resolved this issue by removing the package that was installing fastclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by removing the package that was installing fastclick